# Scraping a website with content added via javascript with PySide in Python

Tags: javascript, python, qt, pyqt4, pyside

I am trying to scrape data from a website using PyQt4 in python. However, this website is adding the data I'm interested in via javascript. Is there a way to ask Selnium to wait for the data before return it? So far, we've tried:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def test():
    print "coucou"

class Render(QWebPage):
      def __init__(self, url):
           self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
           QWebPage.__init__(self)
           self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
           self.timerScreen = QTimer()
           self.timerScreen.setInterval(10000)
           self.timerScreen.setSingleShot(True)
           self.timerScreen.timeout.connect(test)
           self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
           self.app.exec_()

      def _loadFinished(self, result):
           self.frame = self.mainFrame()
           self.app.quit()

def main():
    url = '[redacted]'
    r = Render(url)
    html = r.frame.toHtml()
    page = QWebPage()
    page.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.AutoLoadImages, False)
    page.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, False)
    page.mainFrame().setHtml(html)
    dom = page.mainFrame().documentElement()
    li = dom.findFirst("body")
    print html
    if not li.isNull():
        classe = li.attribute("class")
        text = li.toPlainText()
main()
```

Unfortunately, the content of the page doesn't show the relevant data.
We're using Python 2.7.5 and PySide 1.2.2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the Selenium documentation for `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: We already tried with Selenium and `WebDriverWait` and it doesn't fit our needs.